# IV re-use for Salsa20

Tags: initialization-vector, salsa20

Are their any specific requirements for the IV when using Salsa20?
Is it for example allowed to re-use the same IV when encrypting with the same session key? Should the IV be random? etc

I tried to find some information in the related Salsa20 paper, but I could not really find any mentions of specific Salsa20 IV requirements.

Thanks for the information :)